# Programmatically reduce log in a spark shell

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark

Can I programmatically reduce the log in a spark shell by removing all the `"INFO"` flags?
It is spamming my window and I can't analyze the real output
For example:

```
15/01/09 12:23:02 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 649 bytes result sent to driver
15/01/09 12:23:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 500 ms on localhost (1/1)
15/01/09 12:23:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Stage 0 (count at MainApp.scala:31) finished in 0.520 s
15/01/09 12:23:02 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/01/09 12:23:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: count at MainApp.scala:31, took 0.639191 s
```

Looking for any alternatives if you have some!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This removes most info messages (not all though)

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
// ...
val level = Level.WARN
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(level)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(level)
```

Or as util methods:

```
def setLogLevel(level: String): Unit = {
  setLogLevel(Level.toLevel(level, Level.INFO))
}

def setLogLevel(level: Level): Unit = {
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(level)
  Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(level)
}
```

Comment: Or even `val level = Level.ERROR` if you want to remove warnings also. [Here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html) are all other options you can use.

Answer (score 0):

`spark-submit --options artifact.jar 2>stderr.log`

then use `tail -f stderr.log` in a new window

this should keep your window clean for stdout and able to reach log when you need it

Answer (score 0):

Just add this inside your Spark Source Code and it removes logs

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```